# How to bake ambient occlusion into vertex colors?

Tags: baking, vertex-colors

This is frustrating for me. The UV-textures to vertex cols add-on doesn't seem to work despite the specific instructions. Any other tutorials I can find are either very old or very poor.

I'd like to know how to do this in Blender 2.79. I need vertex colors in my ambient occlusion for use in Shader Forge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Quick overview of the bake process & preview in Blender Render

[image]

---

**How to bake the ambient occlusion into vertex colors**

1. Select the object and **make sure the object has a vertex color layer assigned** in *Object Data* > *Vertex Colors*. If not, create one by clicking the plus button.

   [image]
2. Navigate to the *Render* tab > *Bake*. Select *Bake Mode: Ambient Occlusion* and *Bake to Vertex Color*

   [image]
3. Select the object and hit Bake

---

**Blender Render material setup to see the vertex colors**

1. Select the object's material and enable these:

   - *Shading* > *Shadeless*

     [image]
   - *Options* > *Vertex Color Paint*

     [image]
2. Switch to viewport shading to *Material*

   Optionally, if you want to see your texture blended with vertex colors, you can go to *Texture* tab > *Influence* and set the *Blend: Multiply*
   [image]

---

**Cycles material setup to see the vertex colors**

1. To add vertex colors into node tree, use *Attribute* node with the name corresponding to the object's vertex color layer name (it is named *Col* by default).
2. In the example below, you can see a simple shadeless material where vertex colors and an image texture are combined:
   [image]

Comment: Nice answer. Could please add a short textual description of the process describing the steps so it is searchable and indexable?

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much Jan! :D I was losing hair over this. So simple too.

Comment: Duarte Farrajota Ramos: updated the answer to include written steps

Comment: Is there a way to get this working in Blender 2.90?

Comment: @unfa The feature is now back with 2.92