# No objects or images to bake to error, driving me nuts

Tags: uv, texture-baking, color, vertex-colors

I am trying to bake texture for a model, and I get the infamous error "No objects or images to bake to". I have done a *lot* of googling to try and solve this, and in particular I have read pretty much every post related to that on this forum. It does not help and I still get the error. Here below are some details - please ask for more if necessary. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

**Set up:** I have an obj file, in the same folder as an mtl file along with a jpg picture for the texutre.

**Import:** I open up Blender 2.7 on Linux, default mode, delete the cube and subsequently import the obj file; I can see it alright and I recenter it.

**Texture:** in the materials and texture tabs, I select the jpg image for texture, so that when I set the viewport shading to texture I see the texture on the 3D model view.

**Bake:** making sure that coordinates is set to UV and that Map is set to UVMap in the Mappin dropdown menu of the Texture tab, I then go to the Render tab to the Bake dropdown menu. I click the Bake to Color vertices and choose Texture in the rollout. Clicking bake then yields the error.

**Details:** I make sure that the object is selected, both in the 3D viewport and in the Outliner. In the latter, the icons are on (the eye, the pointer and the camera). I have also been careful enough to open up a second subwindow for the UV/Image editor, and in there I select the jpg image for texture that is in the folder, and I can see the UV map alright. Also, this is all with the Blender Render engine, not with cycles.

What I have in mind after all this, and the reason I want to do it, is that I ultimately want to export the model to a ply file in a way that all vertices are listed *together with an RGB color* for each vertex, which is impossible currently (because color/texture is associated to faces of the mesh and not to vertices), even if I tick the "include vertex color" option in the ply export.

Thanks a looot in advance. I am absolutely out of resources here.

Gustavo

Edit: the thread [How to bake ambient occlusion into vertex colors?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91204/how-to-bake-ambient-occlusion-into-vertex-colors) is different I believe. My question is more specific. However the answer to that thread does include what I was missing: adding a set of vertex colors under the object data tab.

Comment: You need to create set of vertex colors in the *Object Data* tab.

Comment: Good God, rjg: I have been Googling the heck out of this and I never saw mention of creating a set of vertex colors. This makes absolute sense of course, given what I am trying to achieve and given the error message - but I'm a bit new here, so I did not think of it. 

You solved it, anyway. Thanks a million times !

(also, no I don't think this was a duplicate of the thread you mention ...)